# What's the most valuable Avalon Hill wargame?

Tags: pricing, avalon-hill

From a collector's point of view, what is the most valuable wargame published by [Avalon Hill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalon_Hill)?

I'm not interested so much in prices as in knowing if there's a "Holy Grail" in Avalon Hill's wargames catalog before the Hasbro purchase.

I looked in eBay listings and BoardGameGeek, but not being all wargames available for sale, it's hard to get the whole picture.

Comment: This is surprisingly the first question we've had about pricing for board games. I'm unsure if it should be on-topic, so I've [opened a meta discussion about it](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/1573/3389).

Comment: I asked about pricing to narrow the question by giving an objective guideline to answer. I'm mostly interested in the "Holy Grail" part, but that's kind of subjective.

Comment: Well "the most valuable, economically speaking" is asking for economic value -- which means price, hence the pricing tag. You're also discussing eBay Listings, and BoardGameGeek information on what's for sale. I'm not sure what else a "most valuable" "Holy Grail" could be referring to.

Comment: @doppelgreener, fair enough, keep the tag. Can you add an "avalon-hill" tag too? Please :)

Comment: @Rodia Added. :D

Comment: @doppelgreener Great! :D I wanted to hit 150 rep so bad, just to add that tag. You sir are a gentleman and a scholar, and all my Sengir vampires are yours.

Comment: We've already had a meta discussion where the consensus was that there [should not be an "avalon-hill" tag](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/1360/3389). Please do not re-add it.

Comment: @Thunderforge Discussion is open again. Check the comments to [this answer](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/1576/17851).

Comment: A quick ebay search suggests Longest Day might be the answer...

Answer (score 4):

Of course, it all depends upon definitions...  [This article](https://www.tabletoptribe.com/1000-dollar-boardgames/) claims that to go "all in" on Advanced Squad Leader, you need to drop $3200.  But, presumably you meant "a single box"?

If you use [EBay as a way to track prices](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=avalon%20hill%20board%20games&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_udlo=35&_sop=16), as of today, there's a $1K price on Advanced Civilization, and the second highest at $600 is ... Queen's Gambit.  Those are asking prices, not sale prices.

[BoardGame Geek's](https://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/52818/21-most-expensive-games-sale-right-now) list of most expensive games available for purchase today, none of them are AH, but based on the lack of hits on EBay, one can assume it's not a particularly liquid market.

Finally, my original answer to this question, quoted this [article](http://geekandsundry.com/ten-rare-board-games-to-snap-up-the-second-you-can/) to give answer of:  "Star Wars: The Queen's Gambit"

> Star Wars: The Queen’s Gambit: Play as either the trade federation or
>   the Naboo as you reenact the four-fold climax of Star Wars: The
>   Phantom Menace.
>
> Why it’s rare: It’s great, highly complex, and happens to come with
>   155 individual pieces, a 3D Theed palace, 16 dice, and 180 cards. Sure
>   it was released in the comparatively recent year 2000, but prying one
>   of these suckers from the hands of another Star Wars fan will still
>   cost you.
>
> Price: $300-$1000

Comment: You caught me on this one, I should have made clear that I meant Avalon Hill wargames before the company was purchased by Hasbro. Should I edit the question?

Comment: @Rodia If that's what you're interested in, then yes, I think you should add that.  All that said, I'm a bit surprised none of the older Avalon Hill games made that list....  I love those old games, and they are hard to find, and always seem to be very expensive...

Answer (score 4):

Prices vary somewhat naturally, especially if you find a motivated seller, or desparate buyer!  In general, prices are pretty stable and slowly creep up over time.  A reprint can drop prices quickly, but most of the below have difficult rights situations and are unlikely to see full reprints (AoR had a foreign release a while ago).

Games are valuable if they are still played, or weren't printed in enough quantity, preferably both....

Currently, my top 5:

1. $500 - Star Wars: The Queen's Gambit
2. $300 - Advanced Civilization
3. $250 - Axis & Allis Anniversary Edition
4. $200 - Dune
5. $150 - Age of Renaissance

Comment: The highest voted answer on [the meta question about pricing questions](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/1578/3389) indicates that they are on topic, but the community should downvote the answer if it doesn't include information about how they arrived at that price. Could you please add that to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Starting in I guess the mid-1980's, I played a ton of board war games and had a decent collection. I can remember Avalon Hill catalogs from that time, and often the catalogs were printed some years before I eventually purchased the game.

I was always curious what the most expensive thing was in the catalog. The highest price that I recall for a new-in-box game was $85 for [The Longest Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Longest_Day_(game)), in a catalog dated, I believe, 1985.

I purchased a copy in the early 1990's, and I eventually sold it in 2015 for around $200 (open, excellent condition, unpunched).

Comment: While interesting data I am not sure how the price of a game you sold 4 years ago helps determine the most valuable one today.

Comment: Perhaps it was colloquial, but the question specifically referred to the AH catalog.

Comment: That is true but a single game does not give much insight into an entire catalog of games, especially with other example games listed as more valuable.

Answer (score -3):

Although I cannot tell  you the most expensive AH game, I have a large collection of vintage AH games, and the price of them in general continues to rise. Patton's Best is selling for 100-160 dollars, and just a few years ago, a copy would sell for 20-25 dollars. The best way to get a handle on the most expensive AH wargames is to type into Ebay Avalon Hill Wargames, and look at the prices of what is listed. It changes periodically.  For some other companies, some games sell for 500 dollars if you can even find a copy listed.

Comment: The prices listed on any selling platform are usually (and definitely are on ebay) asking prices, which are not, or not directly, indicative of value, which is something that should be considered. Supply and demand is a thing, but it works on a greater scale than any one person asking a certain price for an item.

Comment: I agree.  I just made a general comment from watching the prices of what I have wanted to buy, and have been tracking to see what I could possibly sell elements of my collection for.  The "holy grail" of games, especially Avalon Hill, could be pretty complex. But I bet it changes from time to time.